# Dynamicaly change data attributes in bootstrap-select

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, custom-data-attribute, bootstrap-select

How to change values of data attributes for bootstrap-select?

I want to change `selected-text-format` attribute when `All` is selected.

I try this code : `control.data('selected-text-format', 'count>0').selectpicker('refresh');` And this code doesn't work for me. When i try to get `selected-text-format` from console, i get '`count>0`'.

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/bu5vjdk6/6/)**

Comment: can you provide a complete code sample or fiddle?

Comment: I think the last bit of your script got cut off--looks like there's no closure on the `$('#divRatings').selectpicker().change(function(` bit. At first glance, I think you want to be using `control.attr('data-selected-text-format', 'count>0')` if you want the attribute on the element to change. $.data is storing the info in a reference to the object, not on the element itsself

Comment: @Ted, i tried this... in html layout i can see changes, but not in select behaviour

Comment: i guess it's unclear what the problem is then...what is the expected behavior once the attribute is changed?

Comment: @Ted, when `data-selected-text-format` set to "count>0" then title of select will be default (when you didn't select any element). So i want to show default title when "All" is selected